# How to run Fabric-Ca server/client on multiple hosts with tls enabled?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am running fabric-ca-server on one machine and requesting enroll command from another machine with tls enabled but getting this error

[Fabric-ca-server error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idRB2.png)

[Fabric-ca-client error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whps9.png)
see the highlighted line at the end

can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong or missing?
sorry i cannot post pictures.kindly click on the links to see the pictures which shows the error

Comment: For future reference, please cut and paste the error messages / console output as text in your question rather than linking to screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a common TLS hostname mismatch error where the hostname or IP used in the client request does not match the hostname in the server's TLS certificate.

Assuming you are relying on the fabric-ca-server autogenerate a TLS certificate, you'll need to specify the `--csr.hosts` flag when starting the fabric-ca-server, e.g. `--csr.hosts <IP address>`.  In your case,  would be `172.20.50.158`.  (*Note that it's advisable to use hostnames rather than IP addresses especially when your host system does not have a static IP address*).

Assuming you get past the above, you will also need to set the trusted root certificates flag (`--tls.certfiles`) when running the fabric-ca-client commands; you'll need to obtain the root certificate from fabric-ca-server which would be `$FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/ca-cert.pem` and copy to the machine where you are running the client.

Comment: Thank you for the right solution. I had solved it on my own in the same way thats why reading your answer late but as this is the correct answer so accepting this. Sorry for the linking to screenshots but i was unable to post pictures directly because of the ranking. Thanks again @Gari Singh

Comment: `--csr.hosts` is broken because it ONLY can generate `DNS:` records. It will not never generate `IP:` records, which is REQUIRED in the SAN standard.