# Purpose of csr hosts in fabric ca config

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

What is the purpose of **csr.hosts** in  fabric-ca-server-config.yaml ?
For ex, see below

```
csr:
   cn: ca-org1
   names:
      - C: US
        ST: "New York"
        L: "New York"
        O: ca-org1
        OU: ca-org1
   hosts:
     - localhost
     - example.com
     - ca-org1
   ca:
      expiry: 131400h
      pathlength: 1
```

Are they used to assign a domain name to the CA server itself or used to point node hostnames which are trying to register or enroll ca identities using CA server as fabric-ca client?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the answer but eventually found it myself.

According to [the docs](https://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/users-guide.html#initializing-the-server):

> All of the fields above pertain to the X.509 signing key and certificate which is generated by the fabric-ca-server init.

So as I understand it, `hosts` correspond to the hosts that the CA certificate is valid for.

If run the server binary `fabric-ca-server init --help`, one of the flags descriptions is the csr.hosts provided below:
`--csr.hosts strings A list of comma-separated host names in a certificate signing request to a parent fabric-ca-server`.

So assuming another Root CA sign this CA's csr, csr.hosts tells the Root CA which hosts are valid.

Comment: Ok. Imagine the CA server we build is itself a root CA server and we may not be knowing in advance how many nodes or its hosts this certificate is issued/valid for. What happens in that case ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759669/how-to-run-fabric-ca-server-client-on-multiple-hosts-with-tls-enabled) question and accepted answer. I believe it might clear things out for you.